# A scripting language for videos

Tags: video, script, rendering

I'm searching for a way to to create a video sequence with something like a scripting language.

The goal is to automate the process of generating a script which describes something like:

```
place video x at 0,0
place picture y at 4,4
move y to 0,0 in 4sec
...
```

In the next step I would like to render the video with such a script.
Is the any system for such a task?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like [SMIL](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/smil), though the last time I looked at that it was widely unsupported and buggy.

You might find [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) in combination with a simple, but general purpose like programming language like e.g. Python suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The following software should be able to place videos and add objects by timings:

1. **Manim** ("Animation engine for explanatory math videos"): https://github.com/3b1b/manim 
   There is also a Javascript port: https://github.com/JazonJiao/Manim.js
2. **Processing**: https://processing.org/tutorials/video/
   There is also a Javascript port: http://processingjs.org/
3. **Cinder** https://libcinder.org/docs/ (not tested)